# MySQL output CSV and update from CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a query below where I select a single ID from my database, then update a field for that ID with a 1 to indicate that this record has been processed.  I now need to perform the same process but select 50 ID's and output them in CSV format, and again update each record with a 1 to indicate that these records have been processed.  Any help is appreciated, I'm not sure on the most efficient method to do this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `t_ids` WHERE `f_fetched` IS null LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
$f_id = $row['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE t_ids SET f_fetched = '1' WHERE id = '$f_id'");
```

Comment: You probably need `fputcsv` to write. and an ` LIMIT 50` in the query, does that help, and if not, what is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `t_ids` WHERE `f_fetched` IS null LIMIT 50");
$processed_ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //do whatever processing you need to with that id

    //add the id to the $processed_ids array
    $processed_ids[] = $row['id'];
}

$ids = implode(",", $processed_ids);  //create a comma-delimited string of ids.

//update all rows in 1 query
mysql_query("UPDATE t_ids SET f_fetched = '1' WHERE id IN ($ids)");
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE t_ids SET f_fetched = '1' WHERE  `f_fetched` IS null");
```

Comment: I think that might just set all unprocessed records to 1 regardless of whether they had been processed.  Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: there's no processing in your example.